# Xamarin.Forms: Error Navigation after picking photo from gallery

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xam.Plugin.Media to pick a photo from gallery or camera. In iOS it works all fine but testing in android, after picking the photo from the gallery the app crashs when tries no navigate to another page.

**Error: Java.Lang.IlegalStateExecution: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState**

Here's my code:

```
private async void SelectPicture(PostModel p)
    {


        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", "Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
            return;
        }
        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();


        if (file == null)
            return;



        selfieImg.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
        {
            var stream = file.GetStream();
            file.Dispose();
            return stream;
        });


        await Navigation.PushAsync(new testePage());

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that this might be a threading issue, since your code looks like it might not run in the main UI thread when returning from your Image selection intent.

try doing your navigation call via

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new testePage())
});
```